# PHP script pulling information in wrong format? Trying to get it in JSON

Tags: php, python, json

I have a script in Python pulling information from one service and a script in PHP pulling from another. I'd like to parse and compare the data from both, so obviously I need the information to be in the same format.

The Python script returns a text file in JSON format. Here's a small snippet. Disregard the information inside. I just want to show the formatting.

```
{
    "category": 0,
    },
    "cluster_seed": "24",
    "clusters": {
        "clusters": [
            {
                "center": {
                    "000002": [
                        "massachusetts",
                        "new hampshire",
                        "new jersey"
                    ],
                    "000003": [
                        "Windows",
                        "OSX"
                    ]
                }
```

etc...

However, the PHP script returns information like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Smith
            [engagementScore] => 0
            [firstActivity] => 1386555168108
            [lastActivity] => 1386555168108
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [_deviceType] => Tablet
                    [_os] => Android
                    [_browser] => Chrome
                )

            [segmentMemberships] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [segmentationName] => example
                            [segementationId] => example
                        )

                )
```

I'm not really sure what's going on here. I guess it's printing as a PHP object/array rather than a raw JSON file? I would like it to be formatted exactly as the first snippet is. This is the code in my PHP that pulls this information:

```
$response = curl_exec($session);
$info = curl_getinfo($session);

$body = substr($response, $info['header_size']);
$decoded_result = json_decode($body, true);
```

I thought that `json_decode` would print it in the same format but clearly that's not the case. I tried `json_encode` but that just prints an enormous block of completely illegible information.

Is there any way to print this information in the same format that the first script returns so I can compare the two? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the main purpose of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): take a *string* in JSON format and convert it to either a PHP array or PHP StdClass object, so I'm not sure what your issue is exactly.

From your question, I think what you're trying to do is (in PHP) fetch results from some service, then fetch results from your Python script and compare the two.  You should `json_decode` both results and then you have two neat PHP arrays that are easily traverseable in order to perform your comparison rather than two strings that would be extremely difficult to compare as such.

Think of `json_decode` as PHP's equivalent to Python's `json.load`

Comment: Okay, great. Yup, you understand what I'm trying to do correctly. I was misunderstanding the purpose of `json_decode`. I'll try calling it on the results from the Python script so I have both sets of info in the same format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` will take your raw JSON string and convert it into a data structure that your program understands. This is going to look different between Python and PHP.

What will look identical is the JSON-encoded string that's passed from Python to PHP. That's a universal text format. Just print it out directly, instead of using `json_decode` or `json_encode` first, and it should look closer to what you're expecting. However, it's not going to be nearly as easy to parse this way. You should think about how you plan to compare the data and see what makes the most sense logically.